# Chrome driver not finding ID nor replacing them, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to build my first python selenium bot that checks me into southwest automatically. I've got the code to open southwests' check-in site, but it doesn't type anything. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/thomas****/chromedriver/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.southwest.com/air/check-in/index.html')

conf_num = driver.find_element_by_id("confirmationNumber")
first_name = driver.find_element_by_id("passengerFirstName")
last_name = driver.find_element_by_id("passengerLastName")

conf_num.send_keys("1234")
first_name.send_keys("Thomas")
last_name.send_keys("****")

submit = driver.find_element_by_id('form-mixin--submit-button')
submit.click()
```

Comment: conf_num = driver.find_element("id","confirmationNumber")

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, it is working. Your only issue is that `'1234'` is not a valid confirmation number. Look closely and it shows `Enter valid confirmation #.` under the Confirmation # field.

Replace it with something like the following, for example, and you will see a bigger error.

```
conf_num.send_keys("977089")
```

Comment: When you run it does it automatically type in the inputs? When I run it, chrome opens it navigates to the southwest check in page and then nothing happens.

Comment: Mine does type the inputs, test if it is an issue of it trying to type before the input fields are ready: You could do a simple test by importing `time` and typing `time.sleep(4)` after getting the URL to see if you get anything then. (`time.sleep(4)` will wait for 4 seconds before continuing)

Comment: That is probably not the issue, because it does find the elements, but you could check

Answer (score 0):

I use don't use the function `find_element_by_id()`.
Try using By.

```
conf_num = driver.find_element(By.ID, "confirmationNumber")
first_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, "passengerFirstName")
last_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, "passengerLastName")
... 
submit = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'form-mixin--submit-button')
```

Note that you have to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!! My next question would be, how can I make this automatically fill out the info when it is exactly 24 hours before my check-in time?

Comment: In your case I would 'automate' it a bit further. I find it a bit stressful always changing the code. In Python you can add arguments when you execute a python file. I am not from the US, so I'm not sure what your confirmation number is but I assume that it's your booking number (which is changing for every booking). Thats why I would send the confirmation number like this: `conf_num.send_keys(sys.argv[1])` . Note that you have to `import sys` in the beginning. (Because of the character limit I will explain how to run the code in the next comment)

Comment: When you call your program from your shell you type something like `python script.py`or `python3 script.py`. You can call it instead like this: `pyhton script.py ticketNumber` Like this your program will execute and send for your ticket number the value `ticketNumber` in your program call. My take on this would be to quickly run the script by myself in the above stated way not to worry about the computer being offline and forgetting it etc. But I understand that if you are a frequent flyer, the ticket numbers might be a mess. Thats why I will propose a solution here:

Comment: I don't know if you are using Mac/Linux or Windows but on Mac / Linux systems you can use the `at` command. I haven't used it myself but I know that you can schedule command executions. You could use something like this: `pyhton script.py ticketNumber | at HH:MM MMDDYY` I have to say though that I haven't used this yet and its somehow not working as planned. The man page says that this command should work but it doesn't for me. If you can make it somehow work that it starts at a specific time, great.

Comment: The solution with typing `pyhton script.py ticketNumber`(or python3 depending on your config) still works after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a delay. You need to wait for elements to be loaded and be ready to accept inputs. `WebDriverWait` is used for that. Also, all the `find_element_by_*` are obsolete now. New syntax should be used instead as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('/Users/thomas****/chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.southwest.com/air/check-in/index.html"

driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "confirmationNumber"))).send_keys("1234")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "passengerFirstName"))).send_keys("Thomas")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "passengerLastName"))).send_keys("****")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "form-mixin--submit-button"))).click()
```